# Is there any Java Web Application that dynamically allows to publish the contents of a .properties File and let me modify it?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, properties, crud

As part of all the development of some use cases, I've used a properties file approach to handle almost all the configuration parameters in the project.

Even when this approach is a security safe approach, I need to be able to change this parameters on the application, so I need an admin web module to be able to change at runtime all the configuration on the properties file.

I would like to know if there's any WAR that I can put on my website to enable dynamic web application modification.

I found that the Apache Commons Configuration enables me to do runtime modifications, but I haven't found a CRUD application for properties files.

Does anyone know one?

Comment: As I don't know of any tool that does what you're asking, I won't post an "Answer" to this question... however if I may, here are my 2 cents: an application like that probably doesn't exist because the property-file approach for storing application data is not just unsafe when it comes to security, it also doesn't scale well at all when you're dealing with clustered servers. That's what databases are for, or, even better, J2EE environment entries ('env-entry'). Ironically, had you used J2EE environment entries, you wouldn't need a CRUD app; you could change values through your appserver's GUI.

Comment: As Isaac said, I think it is better to use a database for managing that kind of parameters. Most of the time, if you change a .properties file, you have to restart your server. It looks complicated as the database can be read anytime and the parameter then applied without restarting the app server.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Isaac's and ruffp's comments.  Even if you did manage a way to update the contents of the property files at runtime, this wouldn't solve the issue that most of the properties are likely loaded once and not read again until the application is restarted.  You're best off using Java EE environment entries, or a backing database.

Another option is to use [JMX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html) management beans.  These beans could then be accessed through any JMX management tool, including jconsole - or your could use any available web front-end to access them as well, including any provided by an application server.